# Text along path does not work as expected

Tags: text-object, path

I have a text object that I want to go along path. The problem is, that the text moves only in 2 dimensions.

I expected that the text will be on top of the curve, but it kept offset. But that is not so important as the path not fully control the text.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: try to use the CURVE modifier on the text instead of the "follow path"

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TVkqU7c.png

Comment: I had still problems with the offset and placing the text right on the path. I deleted everything and started again, the origins must be at the same place as when it is created, then it worked as i wanted. 
I somehow miss more option at this, as for example, to have control where on the line the text should be and about the deformations.

Comment: also it deforms the letter and break the geometry https://imgur.com/a/s1yAFwL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- *Text on Curve* only works in 2D (like in Illustrator/InDesign/Photoshop)
- Your *Nurbs curve* is bent in different direction, because it's rotated in 3D space
- Text doesn't fit the *Nurbs curve* length because the curve needs to have applied scale

*Text on Curve only works in 2D. It doesn't care about the curve's 3D rotation*

[image]

*Make sure the Curve has applied scale*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To move an object along a curve, you can use a Follow Path Constraint on the deformed object:

[image: follow path modifier]

But first, you may need to make sure your follower object and curve have their origin aligned, otherwise there will be an offset between them and the deformations might not be as expected. Though this can be use for intended effects too.

As for the Follow Path constraint, you can either do this manually by selecting the follower object, add the Follow Path, set the target and hit Animate Path, or you can just select your follower object, then your curve and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> → Set Parent to Path Constraint

[image: parent with follow path constraint]

This will set the constraint for you, with the target and the animation.

The only thing you may need is to set the Forward and Up axes, which totally depends the context. If you don't know what to use, set your transform orientation to Local, select your follower object with the Move active tool enabled and see which axes you need:

[image: Local axes]

Comment: I dont want to deform an object, I want text follow the path, the deformation of the text object is unwanted.

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: I'd like to see if this option works for me v2.93 / MacOS.

This is what I get for "Follow Path":  https://imgur.com/a/p7hU3oi

which I'm not finding very helpful.

I'll ask it as a separate question and see if that helps.